# Why in the world is my favicon not working?

Tags: html, favicon

New to HTML/CSS, and I've been trying to get favicon working for my site ([here](https://williamlemens.github.io/)) for quite a while now, and I'm stumped. Why is it not working?

I'm accessing it like this:

```
<header>
    <link rel="icon" href="assets/images/icon.png" type="image/png" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/images/icon.png" type="image/png" />
</header>
```

and when I go to https://williamlemens.github.io/assets/icons/favicon.ico it shows up properly.

Comment: May not be the only issue, but a `<link>` tag should only go inside of a `<head>` tag, not `<header>`

Comment: You link is not working. Your tags are not favicon tags. And your favicon is actually showing in that webpage. I have no clue what are you talking about.

Comment: That was it, thanks @chiliNUT

Comment: I'm glad your problem was fixed! However your question is not very helpful now that it's over: as it is very specific, there are little chance someone else will benefit from it. I suggest you to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a file name favicon.ico to display properly. I think you should rename your image file. Hope it helps!